# Iterating over a list within a list in firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, ngfor

I'm having trouble getting the data back in order to use in a `*ngFor`.  The first object is a list and one of its child nodes is also a list and I'm not able to loop over the child list.[

```js
this.afd.list(`/students/${snapshot.key}/languageGoals`).valueChanges()
  .subscribe((res) => {
    this.goals = res;
    console.log(res)
  });
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let goal of goals; let i = index">
  {{goal.domain}}
  <div *ngIf="goal.document">
    <div *ngFor="let a of goal.document">
      {{a.url}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: languageGoals is the first list and documents is the second]

Comment: what do you get if you do `{{goal | json}}` instead of `{{goal.domain}}`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds you have nested collection problem.

```
//collection => Iterable
[{},{},...]

//object array => not Iterable
{
    "key0001": {
        "name": "alice"
    },
    "key0002": {
        "name": "bob"
    }
}
```

Your goal.document is not collection but object array which is not iterable.
You need to change object array to collection.

To handle this, please see here.
[Get list of list firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50031416/get-list-of-list-firebase/50034807)